# How to auto select shoe size on sites like Nike.com

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a piece JavaScript code to automatically select a shoe size on Nike.com. When I run log to debug I get the correct drop-down container. I am having trouble selecting the size. I can't hard code the size since I want this to work on all shoes sizes.

```
function sizeSelect(){
var sizeMenu = document.getElementsByClassName("exp-pdp-size-container exp-pdp-dropdown-container nsg-form--drop-down");
var size = document.getElementsByName("skuAndSize")[0];
for(var i = 0; i < size.options.length; i++) {
    console.log(size.options[i].index);
    if(size.options[i].index == shoesize){
        document.getElementsByName("skuAndSize")[0].options.selectedIndex = i; +
        //gets correct options but can't seem to change the size option on webpage
        break;
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: that's probably because they do use some kind of plugin and not the select directly. This plugin probably needs to be refreshed in order to show the selected value.

Comment: Pure javascript DOM operation, in fact not related with chrome extension concepts.